# why cant I access a public method?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

When I'm using from Main.as:

```
appleObject.setX(50);
```

to call the function which is in Floater.as:

```
public function setX(positionX):void {
    trace("hello");
}
```

from Floater.as, but I get the error 1120: Access of undefined property appleObject.

Main.as: http://pastebin.com/CHMdYM8r

Floater.as: http://pastebin.com/BV4PbfXe

Comment: move the function call somewhere else, not in the class definition like you currently have. For example, put it into the Main() constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what has been said in the comments:

In AS3 class files, all functional code needs to be wrapped in a method (function).

So when the compiler sees this line:

```
appleObject.setX(50);
```

It is expecting it to be either a variable declaration, or a function declaration.    Move that line inside a function, and the compiler error should go away.  As suggested by @DodgerThud in a comment, putting it in the constructor would make a lot of sense:

```
 public function Main():void {
     score.text = "hello";
     addChild(bananaObject);
     addChild(appleObject);
     appleObject.setX(50);
     //...rest of code
```

As an aside, it's also a good practice to not instantiate complex objects in the class scope.  So this would be even better:

```
private var appleObject:Floater;

public function Main():void {
     score.text = "hello";
     addChild(bananaObject);

     appleObject = new Floater();
     addChild(appleObject);
     appleObject.setX(50)
```